# Why clickable is disable when FAB is in LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, floating-action-button

I've got some FAB in LinearLayout with Text for example, and when it's in Linear, Relative or ConstraintLayout clickable is disabled ( onClickListener also), even when I add `android:clickable=true` & `focusable` to both Layout & FAB

Full VIEW

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/constraint_fab_return"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:minWidth="100dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/fab"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/fab"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/constraint_fab_rent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView14"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:text="Odbiór"
            android:textAlignment="center" />

        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab_add_return"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/colorFAB_return"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_manage" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/constraint_fab_rent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minWidth="100dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/fab"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/constraint_fab_return"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/fab">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView13"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:text="Wypożyczenie"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            />

        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab_add_rent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/colorFAB_rent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add" />

    </LinearLayout>



    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorFAB"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/car_rent_list"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_dialer" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:theme="@style/ToolBarStyle" />


    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="77dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/white"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/main_bottom_menu" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/car_rent_list"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar3"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="20dp" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I've tried to bring to the front() and setClicable programmatically? What I'm doing wrong or what I supposed to do?

SDK version is 28 and 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'

And some Java code:

```
public class Main extends AppCompatActivity {

    private FloatingActionButton fabMain, fabRent, fabReturn;

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar3);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        fabMain = findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fabRent = findViewById(R.id.fab_add_rent);
        fabReturn = findViewById(R.id.fab_add_return);


        fabRent.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            Log.i("FAB", "click");
            Intent intent = new Intent(Main.this, SetupRent.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        });

}
```

Comment: so does that mean that you set a click listener to it and when you tap on it nothing happens? Have you tried setting a breakpoint on the onClick method to see if it gets triggered?

Comment: yes i've try debug, logg etc but setOnClickListener never trigger also default click animation isn't working :(

Comment: first, post full XML code instead of a part. Second Paste your java programming code also.

Comment: sure, it's done

Comment: android:id="@+id/constraint_fab_return" in view

Comment: in my case your code worked fine